# Delete Keyframe hot key not working

Tags: keyframes, shortcut, keymap

Hey I just downloaded Blender 3.1.2 and I am trying to use (Alt+I) to delete a keyframe while in the 3D viewport but nothing is happening. It would really speed things up if I didn't have to go to the timeline to delete and add frames.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: ALT+I only works if there is a keyframe at the frame currently selected in the timeline.  You still have to set current frame to the frame you want to delete the keyframe.